# Save Spring-ws webservicetemplate request to DB in XML Format

Tags: java, spring, web-services, marshalling, spring-ws

I am trying to save Spring-ws webservice template request to DB so that I can resubmit the same Webservice request when corresponding site is up.

My configs are as below

```
<bean id="serviceMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="contextPaths">
            <list>
                <value>com.XXX.XXX.ws.XXX.submitorder</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I have a XXXIntegrationClientImpl.java

```
private static final ObjectFactory  XXX_INTEGRATION_LOOKUP_FACTORY  = new ObjectFactory();
com.XXX.XXX.ws.XXX.submitorder.PlaceExternalSystemOrder request = XXX_INTEGRATION_LOOKUP_FACTORY.createPlaceExternalSystemOrder();
// populate the request with all required values
```

The partial Source of PlaceExternalSystemOrder

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"orderInfo"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "PlaceExternalSystemOrder")
public class PlaceExternalSystemOrder {...}
```

I cant modify above since it doesnt belong to us.

Below code doesnt work

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(com.XXX.XXX.ws.XXX.ticketinfo.PlaceExternalSystemOrderResult.class);
Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
m.marshal(request, stringWriter);
```

Just wondering what's the equivalent of above to get request XML, so that I can re-submit the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be a simple solution, unfortunately couldn't find it earlier.

Key was to use Inject configured Jaxb2Marshaller!

```
@Autowired
private Jaxb2Marshaller     serviceMarshaller;

javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
serviceMarshaller.marshal(request, result);
String xml = result.getWriter().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own "PlaceExternalSystemOrder" class with your own customized fields (xml elements).

Let say **PlaceExternalSystemOrder2**, use the same annotations `@XmlRootElement(name = "PlaceExternalSystemOrder")` from the old class as needed and customize the class to meet the required Request parameters.

The steps would be like:

- Create new classes that maps the field to each XmlElements of the request
- Customize the new class "PlaceExternalSystemOrder2" i.e add new fields, getters and setters, annotate the field or setters.
- Use the Class in `createPlaceExternalSystemOrder`
- Change the `JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(com.XXX.XXX.ws.XXX.ticketinfo.PlaceExternalSystemOrderResult.class)` to use `JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(com.XXX.XXX.ws.XXX.ticketinfo.PlaceExternalSystemOrderResult2.class)`
- Populate the Request object and pass it as request in your `m.marshal(request, stringWriter);` - NO Changes here.